# How to solve deadlock in multiple mutexes

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, deadlock

I have a code that required to lock multiple mutexes.

```cpp
void AttackAoeRequest(Player* attacker, int range)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk_attacker(attacker->mtx);

    if (attacker->isInVehicle)
    {
        return;
    }

    //there are a lot of code that need to check before the loop, and these code need to access attacker properties.

    //s_map is the global map class that contains all player in the map.
    for (Player* defender : s_map.GetAllPlayers())
    {
        if (attacker == defender) continue;
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk_defender(defender->mtx);
        if (GetDistance(attacker->position, defender->position) <= 5)
        {
            printf("%d attack %d damage : %d\n", attacker->id, defender->id
                , attacker->attackUpgrade - defender->defenseUpgrade);
        }
    }
}
```

There is a deadlock occured when the attacker is the defender as the same time.
e.g.

```cpp
//playerA and playerB are in the global map class.
std::thread threadA = std::thread(AttackAoeRequest, &playerA, 5);
std::thread threadB = std::thread(AttackAoeRequest, &playerB, 5);
```

**UPDATE**

Actually the threadA, threadB illustrate which situation the cause the deadlock.
AttackAoeRequest is calling from a multithread networking.
The networking is going to handle messages from client and call AttackAoeRequest. There are might be a situation that clientA(playerA) and clientB(playerB) attack each others.

As the code described. There is a situation the player might be the attacker and defender in the same times, and this cause the deadlock.
I had searched about `std::lock` to lock multiple mutexes in same time, but in this case the mutex aren't lock in the same time.

Comment: not what you're looking for: but the normal solution is to not use multiple threads for this sort of processing because it requires locking at too fine a grain to make sense.

Comment: Just for updating a few values you need separate threads? Doesn't appear to me justified to me unless there are long-running loops involved in the hidden code with regular UI updates in between that need to occur in parallel. Otherwise rather just execute the two calls single-threaded one after another. *If* you *really* need MT, then you need a re-entrant (recursive) [mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/recursive_mutex).

Comment: So quake handled this quite simply. It didn't block on sockets and then used a single event management loop. Even if you move the sockets out onto their own thread you can still just push messages to a single threaded event management loop. Otherwise you'll have causality issues.

Comment: @Mgetz I have updated the deadlock situation to make is more clear. In the actual code `AttackAoeRequest()` is going to call from a multithread networking. sorry for not make it really clear.( I just want to illustrate how deadlock happened)

Comment: @jokept192314 sockets code is not naturally multi-threaded, so you may also have undefined behavior if you're interacting with the same socket from multiple threads. AFAIK socket methods are not thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably who is "attacker" and who is "defender" is very fluid, and so you are getting opposite locking order issues.

One defense against deadlocks is to write the code so that it avoids holding multiple locks at the same time. Or, going the other way, make the locking more coarse-grained so that a single lock covers all the objects.

If you have to lock an attacker and defender, you could have the code do it always in the same order. For instance, by address. The object with the lower address in memory is locked  first, then the higher one. Acquire both locks this way, and then execute the all the code that has to work with both of them.

You could have some scoped lock for this which takes two objects. Make a template class supporting `lock_double_guard<std::mutex> dbl_lk(attacker->mtx, defender->mtx);` which puts the two objects in sorted order, and locks them in that order.

In C and C++, pointer to distinct objects may not be compared other than for exact equality, but being able to do `ptrObj1 < ptrObj2` is a common extension. If that makes you nervous, you could just assign an unsigned integer serial number to each object which is incremented whenever a new object is made. The object with a lower serial number is locked first.

Comment: The problem in `lock_double_guard<std::mutex> dbl_lk(attacker->mtx, defender->mtx);` is I didn't have attacker and  defender in the same time. I got attacker first then I got defender after I reach the loop. Making game logic as single thread might bottleneck overall performance since there are a lot of incoming messages. The single lock that covers all the objects is quite interesting.

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal answer to your question. You will have to evaluate what makes most sense in your design and possibly redesign your code. Here are a few avenues to explore:

- Avoid locking in the first place. Use atomics and lock-free techniques to work with player structures. This is not always easy or even possible to do, but may provide good performance.
- Make locking more coarse grained. For example, don't lock individual players, instead lock all players with a single lock. This, obviously, limits parallelism, but this may not be an issue in your code at a large scale.
- Avoid locking multiple players at the same time. For example, complete all you need to do with `attacker` in `AttackAoeRequest`, release `lk_attacker` and then proceed to iterate over `defender`s. Copy/cache the necessary data from `attacker` if you have to to avoid having to access `attacker` during iteration. Your design should allow that some of the cached data will become stale during iteration, if another thread modifies `attacker` while you're iterating.
- Introduce asynchronicity or retries. For example, try locking the `defender` opportunistically, using `try_lock`. If it fails, postpone processing that player and go on with the rest. After you've completed the iteration, release all locks and retry the whole operation on the leftover `defender`s a bit later. Hopefully, by that time other threads will have completed their work with the `defender`s and released their locks. You may need to redo some work on the `attacker` on the second retry, or reuse the previously cached data.
- Separate players processing to different threads. Or, more generally make sure that a given player is never accessed by multiple threads concurrently. Use message passing between threads to implement interaction between players. The message passing mechanism does not need to lock any players, and in fact, locking the players should not be necessary at all. This will also introduce some asynchronicity in the sense that the effects of `AttackAoeRequest` may be applied to `defender`s with a delay - when the corresponding thread processes damage notifications from the attacker.

I'm sure there are other ideas as well.

Comment: Quake could run all of this in a single thread on a Pentium... I'm pretty sure that not using multi-threading at all is also an option.

Comment: Well, I have no idea what code base is there in question. If it's an MMO with hundreds/thousands of players, it would have to be designed quite different from Quake.

Comment: If its an MMO then causality will mean that this sort of thing will require even more serialization. If that's the case it would almost definitely be singlethreaded even if all the *results* of the state machine were handled async. Causality is important 

Comment: I designed this code for MMO server. There is more than 4k connections which is quite slow when I implement this in single thread (using non-blocking socket), so I try to move to IOCompletion port model which is MT networking design. This will make me able to handle more than 4k connections, and maybe faster than the single thread model.

Comment: @jokept192314 did you profile what was slow before switching? Because making this multithreaded can actually slow it down due to data dependencies and locking. MMOs often implement this as a single threaded event management kernel with MT connections that queue in their updates. It's a pretty classic producer consumer problem.

Comment: @Mgetz I have profile the program that hot part is in our damage algorithm which is directly call when read from socket. (read(socket) -> decrypted -> handle message -> call handler -> calculateDamage ->  send response message). Here is a diagram that happened when I use single thread. You can imagine while program calculateDamage others client message is going to block until program calculateDamage done. This is why I want to switch to multithread model for make program able to handle message more than 1 client in the same time.

Comment: @jokept192314 Have you considered sharding your game world? That is process players of each shard in parallel with other shards? Interaction of players between shards should be rare or impossible, depending on the game design.

Comment: @jokept192314 be extremely wary of what you're doing, because what is going to happen is what has happened in *New World* where players can manipulate their ping to manipulate the system because their updates are then locked to their thread. It's fine to take many messages from multiple clients but in an MMO *causality must be preserved*. The easiest way to do that is to have a small 'kernel' of code that determines if an action is valid and updates in memory state that then emits a notification to other code that will let all relevant connections know that it happened.

Comment: But for that "kernel" to maintain causality it is usually single threaded and only applies during things like combat.

Comment: @jokept192314 I would suggest moving player interaction to a single thread but absolutely ensuring that nothing that does not absolutely have to be done by that thread is done by that thread.

Comment: Dear @Mgetz and David Schwartz . There are logics that need to handle monster/npc etc. in map as well, and there are a plenty of maps (~400 maps) that actives in the same time. The single thread model won't be able to handle all of this. The game itself is always interact with others. This is way I can't completely sperate data section for each system to handling in single thread(ex BattleSystem, HealthSystem, etc.).